# Why does Setup.exe run my application, crash, then run it again (successfully)?

Tags: squirrel.windows

EDIT: Apologies I put this in "Squirrel.Windows" when this is more of a Clowd.Squirrel question. I don't have enough rep to make the Clowd.Squirrel tag.

I previously used Squirrel.Windows to "realisify" my app (which was first turned into a NuGet package). I have since upgraded the project to .Net 6, and so I've turned to Clowd.Squirrel.

I still package my app the same way. I then use `squirrel.exe releasify -p C:\project\project.nupkg -r c:\project\Releases\ -i C:\project\my_icon.ico --msi=x64`. It successfully produces a `ProjectSetup.exe` and `ProjectSetup_DeploymentTool.msi`. The msi file works as expected, but the setup file... does not.

When running `ProjectSetup.exe`, it first copies files over to `%localappdata%\project` (including `app-1.0.0`, `packages\`, `Project.exe`, and `Update.exe`). Then it opens my app. After about 10 seconds, it crashes. It then re-opens my app, and it works normally from there. Why? I can't find any windows event logs to explain it, which makes me think it isn't actually a crash, but rather an end that I wasn't expected (but Squirrel is).

Additionally, `ProjectSetup.exe` also does not set up my app in the Start Menu. When I used Squirrel.Windows, it would create a directory `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Project` which contained a shortcut to `Project.exe` (or perhaps it wasn't a shortcut; I can't totally recall). Am I missing some flag/switch or config option?

I'd be happy to provide more information if requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple hours of toiling later, and I found my problem. Please still correct me if I'm wrong, but here are my findings.

And before we get started, I need to reiterate: **This is a problem I had with Clowd.Squirrel**. I again apologize that I have this on the `Squirrel.Windows` tag, but the `Clowd.Squirrel` tag does not exist at the time of writing, and I don't have enough rep to open it.

Now, let me explain what I learned.

### What is "Squirrel Aware"?

For your app to be "Squirrel Aware", it needs to make use of the hooks Squirrel provides. These are the `OnInstall`, `OnEveryRun`, etc. (actual naming might be slightly different). Now, I slightly fib: You can *say* your app is squirrel aware without actually using these hooks. **This was my problem.**

#### Squirrel Aware on Squirrel.Windows

When using Squirrel.Windows, it does not care if you are squirrel aware. And if you aren't, it doesn't complain. For my project, I am only using the `UpdateManager` class, so I don't need squirrel aware-ness.

#### Squirrel Aware on Clowd.Squirrel

When changing over to Clowd.Squirrel, it suddenly complained to me that we weren't being squirrel aware! So, I created the `app.manifest` file, and I included the requisite `<SquirrelAwareVersion xmlns="urn:schema-squirrel-com:asm.v1">1</SquirrelAwareVersion>`. Now Squirrel doesn't complain. But, when I run `ProjectSetup.exe` (or run the deployment tool), it opens, waits about 10 seconds, then closes. Looking back over the [Clowd.Squirrel quick start guide](https://github.com/clowd/Clowd.Squirrel#quick-start-for-net-apps), I realized it might make sense to actually follow it. So I added the hooks as it describes. Now, it doesn't open-close-open. Instead, it installs shortcuts in the correct places (desktop and start menu) and opens up afterwards. All is hunky-dory.

You may then ask: "What if I don't have any plans for those hooks?" Well, if you replace the hook functions with a simple `(a, b) => { }` (or `(a, b, c) => { }` for `onEveryRun`), I found that my app would open, close, then reopen as before. But! Now the first open is very short: just enough time to open a white window, then it immediately closes.

Now wait a second, why can't I just have what I had with Squirrel.Windows -- without all the awareness and whatnot?

**Good news!** You don't need squirrel awareness (still)!

### Actual Solution

- Remove the `app.manifest` file (which made my app squirrel aware)

  - Strictly speaking, you probably need to remove only the `<SquirrelAwareVerson>` tag in `app.manifest`.
- When running squirrel, simply add the `--allowUnaware` flag.

  - This flag was hinted at when I attempted to use squirrel on my app without my app being squirrel aware. But since I had already made it squirrel aware, the warning was nowhere to be found, and I had to find this flag by digging through the source code myself :( (kinda fun tho)

So I end up with:

```
squirrel.exe releasify -p C:\project\project.nupkg -r c:\project\Releases\ -i C:\project\my_icon.ico --allowUnaware --msi=x64
```